# How to change extjs grid single cell background color depending on value changes?

Tags: css, extjs, grid, extjs4, row

To change whole row background color we can use getRowClass, but how to do the same logic only for one cell, and particular column....any ideas?

```
//EXTJS
viewConfig: {
    getRowClass: function(record, index) {
        var c = record.get('change');
        if (c < 0) {
            return 'price-fall';
        } else if (c > 0) {
            return 'price-rise';
        }
    }
}

//CSS
.price-fall { 
        background-color: #FFB0C4;
}
.price-rise {
        background-color: #B0FFC5;
}
```

**EDIT:**

There is a way of doing this with:

```
 function change(val){
    if(val > 0){
        return '<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner" style="background-color:#B0FFC5;"><span style="color:green;">' + val + '</span></div>';
    }else if(val < 0){
        return '<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner" style="background-color:#FFB0C4;"><span style="color:red;">' + val + '</span></div>';
    }
    return val || 0;
}
```

and then just:

```
...
{header: 'Change', width: 75, sortable: true, renderer: change, dataIndex: 'change', align: 'center'}
...
```

but this way grid gets deformed on changes from white to colored background... ???

any other ideas?

**EDIT**
After custom css is applyed to the column, how to remove the same in a short period of time, so it appears to *blink* once when the value has changed? Something like `setTimeout("remove-css()",1000);` or with `Ext.Function.defer(remove-css, 1000);`
Any ideas?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I suggest using `getRowClass` with applying extra cls to needed columns:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    columns: [
        // ...
        { header: 'Change', dataIndex: 'change', tdCls: 'x-change-cell' },
        // ...
    ],

    viewConfig: {
        getRowClass: function(record, index) {
            var c = record.get('change');
            if (c < 0) {
                return 'price-fall';
            } else if (c > 0) {
                return 'price-rise';
            }
        }
    },
    // ...
});
```

### CSS:

```css
.price-fall .x-change-cell {
    background-color: #FFB0C4;
    color:red;
}
.price-rise .x-change-cell {
    background-color: #B0FFC5;
    color:green;
}
```

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tPB8Z/).

Answer (score 11):

There is also another method I found when I am doing another thing;

In column definition:

```
{
    dataIndex: 'invoicePrintedFlag', 
    header: 'Fatura',
    width: 50,
    renderer : function(value, metadata, record) {
        if (record.get('invoiceAddressId') != null){
            metadata.tdCls = metadata.tdCls +" alertedCell";
        }

        return '<span class="iconbox icon-'+ value +'"></span>';
    }
}
```

you can use `renderer` if you manipulate cell completely, here is comes `metadata`:

```
metadata: Object {tdCls: "", style: ""}
```

if you use style it will be added to content DIV inside TD

```
<td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1067" id="ext-gen1432">
    <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-unselectable" style=" text-align: left;" id="ext-gen1426">
    // Content comes here
    </div>
</td>
```

if you use `tdCls`, it will be added to class `attr` of TD

```
<td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1067   alertedCell " id="ext-gen1462">
    <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-unselectable" style="; text-align: left;" id="ext-gen1463">
    // Content comes here
    </div>
</td>
```

Also you can return html as you want.

Comment: This works in Ext 2.3 with the exception that you need to set metadata.css instead of metadata.tdCls

Answer (score 2):

```
renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {

  metaData.tdAttr = 'style="background-color:#b0e987;color:black;"';

  value=Ext.util.Format.number(value, '$ 0,000.00');

  return value;

},
```

Comment: I can't use the row class, because my value is my color. So your solution works for me. The only problem is that the row selection covers the td background. Any ideas ?