# How to style grid depending on the data

Tags: extjs4

I have a grid with a store. When I reload the store I want to add a class to rows which have a  certain flag set in the store data I have reloaded.

How can one accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Ext.grid.View.getRowClass](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.View-method-getRowClass) method.

Basic usage is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7651376/842075). And more advanced example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8037195/842075).