# EXTJS color a cell when Ext.property.Grid filled with content

Tags: javascript, extjs, colors

I have a propertyGrid in ExtJS. I want to color a cell's text when i fill it with content.
The init method:

```
initGrid : function(propertyValues){
    this.model = Ext.decode(propertyValues);
    this.flexColumnGrid.setSource({});
    for(var i in this.model){
      //...
        var value = (this.model[i].value ? this.model[i].value : this.model[i].defVal);
        this.flexColumnGrid.setProperty(this.model[i].key, value, true);
    }
```

defVal is a default value to a property. I use that, when value is empty and there is defVal to property.
I have a value validate method, but i only use that, when a property is change. It's the afteredit event.

```
edit : function(ed,e) {
   //validate values
}
```

I can color the cell's text at this method with

```
Ext.get(e.row.getElementsByTagName('td')[e.colIdx]).addCls('x-grid-wrong-value');
```

where:

```
.x-grid-wrong-value{color:red} //the css
```

but i want to validate the values when the grid is filled by content. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should use `getRowClass` this is an example how to do this:

[How to change background in row or cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034694/how-to-change-extjs-grid-single-cell-background-color-depending-on-value-changes)

And this is an example: [Fiddle for changing background](http://jsfiddle.net/tPB8Z/)